# Communication link failure (||) Thread was being aborted

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis, informix

I face the following problem :

some users complain when they try my web application:

The error i encounter is :

```
IP: System.Web.HttpApplicationState

Agent: IE8

AgentDtails : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.2)

Refrer: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aspx?guid=cb083ebc-d1a8-49ff-b00d-acf208dd67ac

Plateform: WinXP
05/09/2013 09:20:37
Error in: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aspx?guid=cb083ebc-d1a8-49ff-b00d-acf208dd67ac
 Error Message:
 Error Message: Thread was being aborted.
```

and some times :

```
Error Message:ERROR [08S01] [Informix .NET provider]Communication link failure.
```

---

```
 Error Code: -11020
 MEssage: [Informix .NET provider]Communication link failure.
```

These errors are not from specific page or method . i get those errors randomly from time to time and from different pages !!

---

My connection string is :

```
 <add key="connection" value="User Id=XXX;Password=XXXX;Host=aa1;Server=st1;Service=st1;Database=doc; Client Locale=ar_ae.1256; Database Locale=ar_ae.8859-6; Protocol=olsoctcp;pooling=true;Min Pool Size=4;Max Pool Size=200;"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I see that you use pooling. It improves performance because you do need to connect do DB with every HTTP request but such pool must be error prone. There is problem if something in your environment (router, firewall) will think that long lasting and inactive connection between DB server and db pool is really dead and can be disconnected. Then you try to use such connection, db pool believes that such connection is good and usable, but it was closed and is not usable.

How to prevent such error is pool dependent. Some pools have special queries to check if connection is living. You will get only connection that was checked with success. Some pools have timeout time and if connection was not used for that time it is released. You will have to read more about pool you use and configure it. You didn't show what version of .NET Client you use. In "IBM Informix .NET Provider Reference Guide" for Version 3.70 I have found:

*You use the Pooling, Max Pool Size, Connection Life Time, and Min Pool Size
connection string attributes to control the connection pool.*

*The Idle Timeout internal parameter is the standard protocol for removing
connections from the pool and prevents connections from remaining active
indefinitely in the server. Idle Timeout has a value of 120 seconds, which cannot be
changed by setting a new value in the connection string. With Idle Timeout, when
a connection is unused in the connection pool for more than 120 seconds, the
connection is closed and removed from the pool.*

For me 2 minutes is good, but maybe you use other version of client with different settings?